# Applying a custom PyTest run configuration to all child tests in directory?

Tags: pycharm, pytest, jetbrains-ide

I have some tests I'm running with PyTest and Selenium, and would like to be able to run individual tests with the run button in the gutter. I was following this guide to create a custom run configuration from the parent directory of all tests:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-py-test.html

This works for running every test in the directory, but running any of the individual child tests generates a new run configuration without the required settings.

Is there a way to automatically generate a run configuration with specific settings (working directory, environment variables, and additional parameters in particular) for each test?

Comment: **In general:** You can only edit the defaults (template) -- all new Run/Debug Configurations will take settings from there. Because only 1 default is possible, you cannot have one settings for one folder and another for another: all new configs will use  defaults from the template. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#change-template

Comment: @LazyOne Changing the template at the project level may be good enough for now. Does changing a template affect all projects or just the current/open one(s)?

Comment: Current project (since it's a project-specific entity). Don't know if PyCharm allows opening more than one project in one frame like PhpStorm does (where additional project gets attached to the main one) and how it will work in this case. Project opened in a separate frame (window) is a separate project and making such a change in one will not affect another one. Does not affect already existing configurations.

Comment: That should work for me then. Thank you! Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it @LazyOne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware your only option is to **edit the defaults (template) used by all Run/Debug Configurations** when such a config gets created. See the official help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#change-template

[image]

NOTES:

- There is only 1 defaults/template per each run/debug config type.
- Therefore you cannot have one set of settings for this folder and another for some other one. All new configs will use the same template. You can still modify them later of course.
- Editing the template affects only the current project/window (since it's a project-specific entity). Project opened in another frame/window has its own defaults/templates.
- Editing the template does not affect already existing configurations.